# View Pager and Credit Card View

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, android-designer

I have a viewPager that implemented for viewing credit cards. In this viewPager placed a imageView with TextViews to have the card image and attributes. I had not yet aware that credit card design git (https://github.com/sharish/CreditCardView) and started to use it. But when I try to set the attributes, it falls into default and not the arrow attributes. (It worked normally with the text view). I'm using a list of the cards, he constroe view the pager with the amount of cards I have but not to set the values (all created cards are equal), that is, it esa not putting it on the list. Am I doing right?

> PagerView.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   >

    <com.cooltechworks.creditcarddesign.CreditCardView
        android:id="@+id/card_5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:card_expiration="01/17"
        />


</RelativeLayout>
```

> AdapterCard.java

```
public class AdapterCards extends android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter {
    Context context;
    private List<Card> listCards = new ArrayList<>();

    public AdapterCards(Context context, List<Card> listCards){
        this.context = context;
        this.listCards = listCards;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listCards.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view==object;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position){
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View itemView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.pagecards, container, false);

        CreditCardView creditCardView = new CreditCardView(context);
        creditCardView.setCardExpiry(listCards.get(position).cardValid);

        container.addView(itemView);

        return itemView;


    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object view){
        container.removeView((View)view);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to email the Author of the library - his email address is given Harish Sridharan - harish.sridhar@gmail.com

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, but the `CreditCardView` you're calling `setCardExpiry()` on is not the one that gets added to the `ViewPager`. You need to call `findViewById()` on `itemView` to get that one, instead of creating a `new` one.

Comment: Yes Mike M. ,my mistake was not to findViewById the card. It was a very simple mistake (laughs). Thank you for helping me see!!! :D :D